# Set encodeURI for .attr Jquery

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I have this code:

```
code += 'infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: "
<b>'+$("#mapTitel").attr("value").replace(/\"/g,"\\\"")+'</b> 
<br>'+$("#mapStreet").attr("value")+'<br>'+$("#mapPlace").attr("value")"});';
```

I want to use encodeURI for the "value" field of #mapTitel.

I have tried this, but it doesn´t work:

```
code += 'infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: "
<b>'+$("#mapTitel").attr(encodeURI('value')).replace(/\"/g,"\\\"")+'</b> 
<br>'+$("#mapStreet").attr("value")+'<br>'+$("#mapPlace").attr("value")"});';
```

How do I set it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try simplifying you code and it might be easier to con to a solution.
For example you want to encode the "value" field of #mapTitel. So first you get the "value" field of #mapTitel.

```
var value = $("#mapTitel").attr('value');
```

of course if `#mapTitel` is an input field and you want to get it current value you should use `.val()`

```
var value = $("#mapTitel").val();
```

now you can encode it

```
value = encodeURI(value);
```

Comment: musa, sorry for my noob question, but how do I insert it in between my code? because, I have multiple fields with the name "value"?